# Postgres empty SELECT clause "affects rows"

Tags: postgresql

I stumbled upon Postgres behaviour, which I do not understand. I enter this simple query. Please notice that there's no expression in `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS data(value);
```

Server replies with

```
Query executed OK, 3 rows affected.
```

According to the documentation for `SELECT` statement, the empty clause seems to be perfectly valid, but I can't understand, what *affected rows* mean in this case. `EXPLAIN` gives me simple "values scan" query plan. When I change `SELECT` to `SELECT *`, the query works as expected and returns table with three rows.

What does that `SELECT <nothing> FROM ...` do?
My Postgres version is 9.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL allows empty `SELECT` lists (the SQL standard does not allow that).

"3 rows affected" must be something that your client says when it receives a result set with three rows. The result set *does* contain three rows, even if they contain no column. Perhaps your client displays the result set as if it were empty, but it isn't.

Comment: You are right, I tried different client and it replies just "(3 rows)", but not "affected", which seems correct. Seems like some bug in the client I used previously. Thank You very much.